# R function for looping over a string with unique values

Tags: r, string, loops, foreach

I am working on a project where I have to download more than 10 million records on a relatively small server. So instead of just downloading the entire dataset, I have to download it in smaller sections. I am trying to create a loop that will call batches of the data based on date. I'm used to coding in Stata where you can call a local by using `x' or some variant within a string. However, I can't find a way to do this in R. Below is a small piece of the code I'm using. Basically, whenever I try to run this 'val' and 'val2' aren't updating with the dates in the defined lists so the output literally just reads as if the server is trying to search between 'val' and 'val2' instead of between '20190101' and '20190301'. Any suggestions for how to fix this are greatly appreciated!

```
x<-c(20190101, 20190301)
y<-c(20190301, 20190501)
foreach (val=x, val2=y) %do% {
     data<-DBI::dbGetQuery(myconn, "SELECT * FROM .... WHERE (DATE BETWEEN 'val' AND 'val2')")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a basic loop

```
x<-c(20190101, 20190301)
y<-c(20190301, 20190501)

data_all = c()

for(i in 1:length(x)){
  
  query = paste0("SELECT * FROM .... WHERE (DATE BETWEEN '",
  x[i],  "' AND '",  y[i], "')")
  
  data <- DBI::dbGetQuery(myconn, query)
  data_all = rbind(data_all, data)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sprintf` you can construct the query and use `lapply` + `do.call` to combine the results into one dataframe.

```
x<-c(20190101, 20190301)
y<-c(20190301, 20190501)

input <- sprintf("SELECT * FROM .... WHERE (DATE BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s')", x, y)
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(input, function(x) DBI::dbGetQuery(myconn, x)))
```

Using `purrr::map_df` is a bit shorter.

```
result <- purrr::map_df(input, ~DBI::dbGetQuery(myconn, .x))
```